# How to Hide CustomTabBar when i Navigate to OtherViews from its ChildViews in swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

iam new to swiftui and i got a requirement to create CustomTabBar and hide that CustomTabBar in other contentViews except its child views and
I have created CustomTabBar and i want to hide this custom tab bar when i navigate to other views from CustomTabBar child views.

Here is my `CustomTabBar` code:

```
struct CustomTabBar: View {
@StateObject private var viewModel = CustomTabBarViewModel()

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack {
                tabContentView()
            }.navigationBarHidden(true)
            
            HStack {
                TabView(image: "ic_Home", selectedTab: $viewModel.selectedView)
                TabView(image: "ic_Notepad", selectedTab: $viewModel.selectedView)
                TabView(image: "ic_Cart", selectedTab: $viewModel.selectedView)
                TabView(image: "ic_Library", selectedTab: $viewModel.selectedView)
                TabView(image: "ic_Profile", selectedTab: $viewModel.selectedView)
            }
            .frame(width: .infinity)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
        .padding(.vertical)
    }.background(Color.lightOrangeColor)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}

@ViewBuilder
   private func tabContentView() -\> some View {
       switch viewModel.selectedView {
           case "ic_Home":
               HomeView(parentViewModel: viewModel)
           case "ic_Notepad":
               TestsSegmentView(selectedSegment: 0)
           case "ic_Cart":
               Color.green
           case "ic_Library":
               Color.red
           case "ic_Profile":
               Color.blueColour
           default:
               EmptyView()
       }
   }
}

struct TabView: View {
let image: String
@Binding var selectedTab: String

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { button in
            Button {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                    selectedTab = image
                }
            } label: {
                VStack {                    
                    Image(image)
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .foregroundColor(selectedTab == image ? Color.blueColour : Color.grayTextColour)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 50)
    }.frame(height: 20)
}
}
```

please help me to How to hide this Custom. tabbar when i navigate to otherViews from Its Child Views in swiftu